# Loading an Android video from an html link

Tags: android, html, video, hyperlink, sd-card

I have a webview and one of the links has:

```
<a href=video.mp4>click here</a>
```

When I click it I wanted it to open a video file that is in the same directory but nothing happens. I have also tried

```
<a href=file:///sdlocation/video.mp4> click here</a>
```

With the same results.

How can I load local videos and pictures using an html link?

Comment: do you mean: <a href="video.mp4">click here</a>?

Answer (score 1):

Try your same link, but prepend with a directory qualifier, like so:

```
<a href="./video.mp4" target="_blank">Click Here</a>
```